# Are GatsbyJS GraphQL queries tied to the component where it's written?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have a couple yaml files with meta content that represent pages of a site that get ingested by Gatsby's data source/transform system - one of the files looks something like this:

```
path: /about/
pageTitle: About Us
metaDescription: Learn more about our team and what we do
...
```

I also have a base yaml file with meta content that other pages default to if meta content is missing or was not particularly written for that page.

```
path: Base
pageTitle: Welcome to our website
metaDescription: We are the leading company of industry x in ...
...
```

My current solution is to pass a graphql query variable `$slug` that is the page path, i.e., `/about/` via the `onCreatePage` hook in `gatsby-node.js`,

```
exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, boundActionCreators }) => {
  const { createPage, deletePage } = boundActionCreators;
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const oldPage = Object.assign({}, page);
    deletePage(oldPage);
    createPage({
      ...oldPage,
      context: {
        $slug: oldPage.path
      }
    });
    resolve();
  });
};
```

add a graphql query in `layout/index.js` filtering for Base meta content,

```
query BasePageQuery {
  pagesYaml(path: { eq: "Base" }) {
    path
    pageTitle
    metaDescription
    ...
  }
}
```

and a more generic graphql query **on every single page** where field `path` (from the yaml file) matches the query variable `$slug`:

```
query AboutPageQuery($slug: String) {
  pagesYaml(path: { eq: $slug }) {
    path
    pageTitle
    metaDescription
    ...
  }
}
```

Instead of adding a graphql query onto every single page, I'm thinking instead to add both queries into `layout/index.js`, and avoid having to manually add the above query to all other pages.

```
query BasePageQuery($slug: String) {
  base: pagesYaml(path: { eq: "Base" }) {
    path
    pageTitle
    metaDescription
    ...
  }
  page: pagesYaml(path: { eq: $slug }) {
    path
    pageTitle
    metaDescription
    ...
  }
}
```

However, it isn't working as expected - `this.props.data` in the layout component only returns the base content and completely ignores my second query. It appears as if the query is tied to my `layout/index.js` component, and the $slug variable isn't reflecting the page component that's being rendered.

Which brings me to my question(s) -

1. Are graphql queries tied to the component that it's being written in? In this particular case - is `$slug` always going to be whatever `path` `layout/index.js` is?
2. Is there a way to print out graphql variables, or somehow verify what the variable is at a given point in time?
3. Is there a better solution to what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't quite understand the question about where GraphQL queries are tied to but I think that it will be more clear to you when you understand that you passed `slug` as a variable to the `createPage` function in your `gatsby-node.js` file. So for every page that is being created when you run `createPage`, the `slug` variable will be whatever you passed to it.
2. Again, do that in your `gatsby-node.js` file, in the `createPage` function.
3. `gatsby-config.js` would be a more appropriate place for the "default" or "base" information you want. Check out the example `gatsby-starter-blog`. There are information in the [`gatsby-config.js`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/blob/master/gatsby-config.js#L3) that are then being queried in the [`blog-post.js` template](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/blob/master/src/templates/blog-post.js#L71) alongside with the post's data.

Comment: Appreciate the response. To clarify 1., does Gatsby pass query variables to layout components? After messing with it - it appears it only makes these variables present in page components.

Comment: Currently and in Gatsby v1, GraphQL queries can only be exported by page/template components. Once these are exported, Gatsby takes them and apply your context object on them.

With Gatsby v2 this will be different and you will be able to write GraphQL queries from any components.